# Не выходит установить bluebird bcrypt-as-promised

Tags: node.js, npm

`npm i --save bluebird bcrypt-as-promised`

Вбиваю эту команду и выдает эти ошибки
[image: one]

[image: two]

Answer (score 1):

Вам <s>Русским</s>Английским языком написало, что не найден Python в `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.EXE`

Попробуйте [установить Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) на компьютер и запустить команду снова

Comment: но у меня установлен пайтон

Comment: @TerraTor в таком случае установите PYTHON переменную окружения  `set PYTHON=D:\Python\bin\Python.exe` или где у вас расположен .exe

Answer (score 1):

Пайтон 3х не подходил, поставил версию ниже и все заработало.
Можно закрывать

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/208384)

Comment: @Silento, это ответ, причём хороший - установить Питон 2 вместо 3.